# How to control the variable in emacs?

Tags: emacs

The page 49 of org mode manual has the following comment.

```
"To limit tag inheritance to specific tags, or to turn it off entirely, use the variable org-use-tag-iheritance and org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance."
```

It seems that I should set those variables to 1 or t inside emacs. Is this correct? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`M-x set-variable RET var RET value` (from http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/emacs/emacs_478.html)

Answer (score 2):

To configure these permanently, you can use `(setq variable value)` in your .emacs file. Alternatively, as these variables are both defined with `defcustom`, you can also use:

`M-x customize-variable org-use-tag-iheritance`
and `M-x customize-variable org-tags-exclude-from-inheritance`

to configure them either temporarily or permanently.